# Status code 500 when installing jenkins as windows service

Tags: windows-services, jenkins, slave

I have finally managed to get to the "install as a windows service" page. 
now when I click install I get the following:

> Status Code 500

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.(Unknown Source)
at hudson.lifecycle.WindowsInstallerLink.doDoInstall(WindowsInstallerLink.java:111)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:282)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:149)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:88)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:103)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:561)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$12.dispatch(MetaClass.java:373)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:561)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:477)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:159)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:249)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:335)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:378)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:94)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:244)
at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please advise... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the reason is that the required .NET framework 2 is not installed. [See here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallSlaveasaWindowsservice%28require.Net2framework%29)